# ZXing not working on first page of the Navigation Page

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to implement ZXing scanner in my application by using it in a page

[image: page]

It worked when I tried to use in the first time, but, after some hours into the project, I went back to test it, it was not working anymore. I assume it is some problem with some configuration, because I tried it with the same code in a brand new application and it works normally.

I'm using a webcam to scan the barcode.

**EDIT**

Found out that the problem is with the Navigation Page, I am using the Scanner inside the **first*** page on the navigation page.

*In the second page it works properly.

Comment: Without any hints or codesnippets that show what you tried, there is no possibility to help you.

Comment: @AlexS I added what is the problem, I just need to found how to solve the problem now.

Comment: How are you adding the scanner, in XAML or in the code-behind? I ask because I've ran into issues where when it's declared in XAML, it would appear to freeze, and what I ended up doing was declaring it in the code behind, then destroying it when it was done, and recreating it when it was needed again.

Comment: @Andrew I tried both ways, in the XAML and code behind, appears to have no difference.

Comment: @Pancabiel You could download the sourfiles from the GitHub for reference.https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile https://github.com/selmanalpdundar/Scanner